# Is it ok to move a unique_ptr while it's in its own destructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

Yesterday I came across a class that would in its destructor call a method that ended up returning a unique_ptr to `this`. That was obviously a problem, because that would cause a double delete, so I added `.release()` to that method call and all was fine again. It's a strange situation, though, and I wanted to have some closure that this is an alright thing to do.

To give an example, I reduced this situation to its essence:

```
#include <memory>

class B;

class A {
public:
  A(std::unique_ptr<B> b);

  std::unique_ptr<B> removeB();

private:
  std::unique_ptr<B> b_;
};

class B {
public:
  B();
  ~B();

  void setA(A *a);

private:
  A *a_;
};

A::A(std::unique_ptr<B> b)
  : b_(std::move(b))
{
  b_->setA(this);
}

B::B()
  : a_(nullptr)
{
}

B::~B()
{
  if (a_)
    a_->removeB().release();
}

void B::setA(A *a)
{
  a_ = a;
}

std::unique_ptr<B> A::removeB()
{
  return std::move(b_);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  A a(std::make_unique<B>());
}
```

I think this is basically like doing this:

```
class B;

class A {
public:
  A(B* b);
  ~A();

  B *removeB();

private:
  B *b_;
};

class B {
public:
  B();
  ~B();

  void setA(A *a);

private:
  A *a_;
};

A::A(B *b)
  : b_(b)
{
  b_->setA(this);
}

A::~A()
{
  delete b_;
}

B::B()
  : a_(nullptr)
{
}

B::~B()
{
  if (a_)
    a_->removeB();
}

void B::setA(A *a)
{
  a_ = a;
}

B *A::removeB()
{
  B *result = b_;
  b_ = nullptr;
  return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  A a(new B());
}
```

It works alright, and I don't have any static analyzers or valgrind complaining about it, but I would like to have some sort of confirmation that this is an ok thing to do.

Comment: Whether or not "this is an ok thing to do" depends on how the rest of the application uses these classes. So, I'm afraid you're the only one who can determine if "this is an ok thing to do".

Comment: I meant this as more of an essential question: is this guaranteed to work with any compiler, on any platform, with any stdlib implementation (excluding bugs)?

Comment: That's a really tricky question. I think it really depends on the compiler implementation. Not 100% sure, but I see no issue with this if compiler supports c++11

Comment: Since these classes are so tightly coupled, can you not simply merge them ?

Comment: That looks very dodgy to me because while `A`s destructor is destroying the `unique_ptr` the destruction of `B` calls the `unique_ptr` methods.

Comment: Why does your destructor need to call a function that returns a `unique_ptr`, that references `this`?    The reason I ask is that creating (or returning) a `unique_ptr` is associated with either initialisation of an object (`*this` cannot be initialised in its destructor) or preventing its destruction (if the destructor is invoked, the destruction of the object has already irrevocably commenced).   Forcing the `unique_ptr` to release (and therefore not destruct the object) will work, but the need to do that at all in a destructor suggests a badly broken design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got something quite tangled up going on here. First of all, you have `class A`, which has a `unique_ptr` to a `B`. This suggests an ownership (or parent/child) relationship: `A` owns a `B`. The fact that `B` in turn has a simple pointer to `A` which is not set in the constructor but instead through a `setA` call seems to confirm this: `A` gets a child `B`, then calls `setA` on it with a simple pointer to tell `B` about its parent.

So when is `B` destroyed? Answer: during `A`'s destruction, via `unique_ptr`'s destructor. Why would `B` then try to pull itself off `A` when this is happening with the `removeB` call? This seems like confused code that just doesn't need to be there. Likely the correct thing is to simply do nothing in `B`'s destructor, everything will be then destroyed correctly.

So my suggestion is to have an empty destructor for `B` instead.

To answer your specific question: is there anything wrong with this `removeB().release()`: I have a feeling that yes there is. The `B` destructor is being called during `A`'s destruction and therefore occurs during the destruction of the `unique_ptr` member of `A`. Your `removeB` call therefore passes a partially-destroyed object to `unique_ptr`'s move constructor. I would not be surprised if this is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Looks like in our specific case `removeB` was supposed to always return `nullptr` if it's called in the destructor, but there was a bug causing it to return an actual valid pointer instead.